# Override the Numpad_Dot

Tags: java, android, onkeydown, textchanged

I have 4 edit texts; `oct1`, `oct2`, `oct3`, `oct4`. These edit texts are the type `numberDecimal`. I have initial focus on `oct1`. I need it so when the user presses `.` (numpad dot) it will **not** enter the `.` the oct, clear focus and focus on the next edit text.

This *should* be easy, but is surprisingly frustrating for me. This is what I have tried.

Overriding `onKeyDown`. This won't even produce the logs.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT){
          oct3.clearFocus();
          oct4.requestFocus();
          return true;
       }
       Log.d("KeyCode", String.valueOf(keyCode));
       Log.d("event", String.valueOf(event));
       return false;
}
```

Then this. I have many different variants of this. I have been able to switch focus with this, but not delete the `.`.

```
    oct3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(count > 0){
                if(s.charAt(s.length()-1) == ".".charAt(0)){

                    Log.d("Sequence", "Noticed a \".\"");
                    isPeriod = true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("Sequence", "Noticed a \""+s+"\"");
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(isPeriod){
                s.delete(s.length() -1, s.length() -1);
                oct3.clearFocus();
                isPeriod = false;
                oct4.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting it in the `onTextChanged`:

```
  listener = (new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(count > 0){
                if(s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '.'){
                    Log.d("Sequence", "Noticed a \".\"");
                    CharSequence text = s.subSequence(0, s.length()-1);
                    Log.d("VIEW CLICKED:", String.valueOf(getCurrentFocus()));
                    setTextAndAdvance(getCurrentFocus(), text);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Sequence", "Noticed a \""+s+"\"");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```